# How to select rows that have continous value for a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table like below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LINE](
[ID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[LINE_NUM] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into LINE select '01201301090100600004', '1'
insert into LINE select '01201301090100600004', '2'
insert into LINE select '01201301090100600004', '3'
insert into LINE select '01201301090100600004', '4'
insert into LINE select '01201301090100600005', '1'
insert into LINE select '01201301090100600005', '4'
insert into LINE select '01201301090100600005', '5'
insert into LINE select '01201301100045200002', '1'
insert into LINE select '01201301100045200002', '2'
insert into LINE select '01201301100045200002', '3'
insert into LINE select '01201301100081300008', '1'
insert into LINE select '01201301100081300008', '3'
```

i want to select records where LINE_NUM column is continuous. It should start with 1. So i am looking to select only the below

```
   '01201301090100600004', '1'
   '01201301090100600004', '2'
   '01201301090100600004', '3'
   '01201301090100600004', '4'
   '01201301100045200002', '1'
   '01201301100045200002', '2'
   '01201301100045200002', '3'
```

How would i do this?

Edited Question:

What i am looking is to get distinct ID's where the LINE_NUM starts with 1 and also if there are more than one LINE_NUM for a ID then check to see if they are sequential and retrieve those ID's?

i used this to get it

```
SELECT id,
   m.line_num,
   m.new_line_num
FROM   (SELECT t.line_num AS old_line_num,
           t.*
    FROM   (SELECT t.*,
                   Row_number()
                     OVER (
                       partition BY clm_id
                       ORDER BY line_num ) AS new_line_num
            FROM   line t) t) m
WHERE  m.line_num <> m.new_line_num
```

Comment: @Neeku SELECT ID
       ,m.LINE_NUM
       ,m.new_line_num
FROM (
       SELECT 
              t.LINE_NUM AS old_line_num
              ,t.*
       FROM (
              SELECT t.*
                     ,row_number() OVER (
                           PARTITION BY CLM_ID ORDER BY LINE_NUM
                           ) AS new_line_num
              FROM  LINE t
              ) t
       ) m
WHERE m.LINE_NUM <> m.new_line_num

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `row_number()`.  If the values are sequential (a more accurate term than "continuous"), then the difference will be a constant:

```
select id, line_num
from (select t.*,
             min(diff) over (partition by id) as mindiff,
             max(diff) over (partition by id) as maxdiff
      from (select t.*,
                   (line_num - row_number() over (partition by id order by line_num)) as diff
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t
where mindiff = maxdiff and mindiff = 1;
```

If you just want to find `id`s that have no gaps, you don't even need window functions:

```
select t.id
from table t
group by t.id
having (max(line_num) - min(line_num) + 1 = count(distinct line_num));
```

Comment: I am still getting ID's with broken line numbers

Comment: @user176047 . . . Can you edit your question and provide some examples?  Or, better yet, set up a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: @user176047 . . . The query in your revised question is *not* the query in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)` to order by the ID column. Then use that to check if the next row has  `Line_Num + 1`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT IdNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID), *
    FROM dbo.LINE
)
SELECT ID,LINE_NUM 
FROM CTE
WHERE (SELECT LINE_NUM FROM CTE c2
       WHERE c2.IdNum = CTE.IdNum + 1) = LINE_NUM + 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8703b/3/0)</kbd>

Comment: it does take a lot of time to run but still selects ID's with non-sequential LINE_NUM

Answer (score 0):

May be we can do like this also

```
declare @Line  TABLE (
    [ID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Line_NUM] [int] NOT NULL
    ) 

    insert into @Line select '01201301090100600004', '1'
    insert into @Line select '01201301090100600004', '2'
    insert into @Line select '01201301090100600004', '3'
    insert into @Line select '01201301090100600004', '4'
    insert into @Line select '01201301090100600005', '1'
    insert into @Line select '01201301090100600005', '4'
    insert into @Line select '01201301090100600005', '5'
    insert into @Line select '01201301100045200002', '1'
    insert into @Line select '01201301100045200002', '2'
    insert into @Line select '01201301100045200002', '3'
    insert into @Line select '01201301100081300008', '1'
    insert into @Line select '01201301100081300008', '3'
    ;WITH CTE AS 
    (
    select ID,Line_NUM,RN=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION by ID ORDER BY Line_NUM ) from @Line
    ),CTE2 AS
    (
    Select distinct 
    ID,Line_NUM,RR = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION by ID ORDER BY  Line_NUM )
    from CTE 
    WHERE Line_NUM = RN 
    GROUP BY ID,Line_NUM,RN 
    )
    ,CTE3 AS
    (
    Select C.id,C.Line_NUM,RANK() OVER(Order By c.id) as t_index FROM CTE2 C
    GROUP BY C.ID,C.RR,c.Line_NUM
    )

    Select ID,Line_Num from 
    (Select DISTINCT cc.ID,CC.Line_NUM,COUNT(CC.t_index)OVER (Partition by cc.ID)RS from CTE3  CC)Z
      WHERE RS > 1
```